# Function of の in these phrases

Tags: particle-の

I know that の is used as a noun modifier.
But recently I've come across these pharases 心の強い人,母の作れる料理.

The first phrases will be sth like strong person of heart/mind, which somehow differs from correct meaning strong-heart person (I think it should be 心が強い人).
And the second one, since 母 clarify meaning for 作れる (as in 私にできることはない), I think it should be 母に作れる料理.

So why の are used in these case?

Comment: Are you sure that に wouldn't change the meaning in your second sentence? What about 母が作れる料理?

Comment: possibly related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4346. [This answer](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9453/796) also went into this usage of "の" a little bit.

Comment: @user1205935 Could you tell me the difference? From what I learned, both に & が in this case mean the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both could be が without changing the meaning. In this case, though, it is possible to use の in basically the same way without changing the meaning. This の is not the same as the の that you learned as a noun modifier, like in 私の家, but rather the nominative case (主格). I am not an expert on grammar, but there is a lengthy post on this subject [here](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/4230142.html) (in Japanese). You can also check it on wikipedia in whatever language you desire.

If you cannot read that page, basically it says that this construction comes from a classical Japanese construction that uses the word order ～の＋連体形{れんたいけい}＋名詞{めいし}, or some object plus a participle plus a noun. The example given on that page is the old phrase 「嘴の赤き鳥」＝嘴が赤い鳥が. In the example 心の強い人, 心 would be that object, の is the particle in question (格助詞), 強い would be the participle adjective, and 人 would be the noun.

If I've made any errors here then please someone who is better at grammar correct me, of course!

Comment: I am not terribly good at grammar, but I think perhaps this usage is limited to dependent clauses.  See [大辞林's definition under 1-2](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%AE&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=1&pagenum=1&index=115246000000).