# meaning of の after すごい

Tags: grammar

> せっかくならもっとすげえ**の**用意してもらいてえもんだな

why is it there?

Comment: The following should answer your question https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9421/45489

Answer (score 2):

の turns an adjective into a noun, taking it from "amazing" (すごい) to  "something amazing" (すごいの).

If we take your sentence and simply write it in a more standard way, we get: せっかくならもっとすごいのを用意してもらいたいものだ。

*せっかくなら*

*If you are going to go out of your way,*

*用意してもらいたいものだ。*

*(then come on...) I'd like you to prepare*

*もっとすごいのを*

*something even more amazing!*

See: [Particle の (Nominalizer)](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/particle-no-nominalizer/)